# Celery setup for multiple Django Projects running in Docker Swarm

Tags: celery, docker-swarm, django-celery

We have multiple **Django Projects** (in dedicated GitHub repos) running in **Docker Swarm**. We want to set up **Celery** in such a way that it can be used across all the projects.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am looking for more ideas and considerations while architecting this.

I have tried setting it up on one of the projects and invoking its tasks from the other projects by using the `send_task` method. It kind of works in one direction.
How can I make it execute tasks whose definition is not present in the project in which it is running? Or in other words, how can I execute un-unregistered tasks from other projects?